# AWS-Serverless template reference Globals environment variables within the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I am trying to create a AWS SAM template.yaml to create a lambda accessing a DynamoDB table resource and define the IAM permissions of this lambda.

I want the table name to be in an environment variable and I want it to be different depending on the development state (dev-prod etc).

However I cannot find a way to define the permission ARN. I have the following template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Lambda to API-Gateway endpoints mapper for Pantrimony

Parameters:
    stage:
        Type: String
        Default: dev
    region:
        Type: String
        Default: eu-central-1
        
Globals:
  Function:
      Environment:
            Variables:
                VICTUALS_TABLE: !Sub "Victuals-${stage}"
    
Resources:
    GetVictuals:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
            Handler:  Pantrymony.back::Pantrymony.back.Lambda.ApiFunctions::GetVictuals
            Runtime: dotnet6
            Description: Lambda handler for API Gateway 
            MemorySize: 512
            Timeout: 60
            Events:
                GetVictualsApi:
                    Type: Api
                    Properties:
                        Path: /victuals
                        Method: get
            Policies:
                - Statement:
                        - Sid:  DescribeTablesPolicy
                          Effect: Allow
                          Action:
                          - dynamodb:DescribeTable
                          Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-central-1:926574008145:table/${self:Globals.Function.Environment.Variables.VICTUALS_TABLE}'
```

How can I reference a Globals variable in the rest of the template yaml.
As you can see I tried the ${self:...} term which is working for templates in the Serverless-framwork (for variables defined in provider.environment...) but in AWS-SAM it doesn't seem to work.
Is there another way to define some global variable which will be accessible throughout the template?